# How do you add a vendor javascript asset to a large "vendor.js" with Laravel Mix, if the asset is not available with npm?

Tags: php, laravel, npm, composer-php, laravel-mix

For example, both jquery and jstree are available with npm.

Therefore, in my Laravel project I can add this to the file "webpack.mix.js":

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract(['jquery','jstree']);
```

When running "npm run dev" then indeed both jquery and jstree ends up in the file "public/js/vendor.js" as expected according to the documentation about [Vendor Extraction](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#vendor-extraction) (which uses "extract(['vue'])" in the example)

As far as I understand, this works because both jquery and jstree are located in "node_modules" thanks to being defined in my "package.json"  (by defining "jquery": "^3.2" and "jstree": "^3.3.9")

However, how should I use Laravel Mix to put some other javascript file asset into my large generated "vendor.js" file if that other asset is not available with npm but for example I instead retrieved it with composer?

For example the file "jsvalidation.js" from [laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation)

I added that dependency into my project with "composer.json" (by using "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "^3.0") and then ran "composer update".

Then I used "mix.copy" in "webpack.mix.js" since I have found [some info about the jsvalidation and laravel-mix](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Laravel-6-installation):

Quote: "Keep in mind to copy your files using mix, so add in webpack.mix.js file":

```
mix.copy('vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/public/js/jsvalidation.min.js', 'public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/');
```

(as you might notice the above linked page is for "Laravel-6-installation" but currently there seems to be no documentation for Laravel 7 which I am using, but anyway, regarding the laravel-mix stuff I am asking about it should not be depending on which version of the jsvalidation library I am using)

So I have added the above "mix.copy" row to my "webpack.mix.js" file but then what should I to get that jsvalidation file into the large "vendor.js" together with jquery and jstree?